# Need SQL help - How can I select rows to perform an insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried to make the title as clear as possible... here is my scenario:

I have 2 tables (let's call them table A and table B) that have a similar schema. I would like write a stored procedure that would select specific columns of data out of table A, and insert this data as a new record in table B.

Can someone point me in the write direction to make such a query? I am unsure how to "Hold" the values from the first query, so that I may then perform the insert.

I am trying to avoid making a query, processing it with C# and then making another query...

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO B (Col1, Col2) SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM A
```

Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this as a single query from C# like this:

```
Insert into tableB (col1, col2, col3) select col1, col2, col3 from tableA where ...
```

The trick is that column names need to be in the same order and compatible types.

Answer (score 0):

use a SELECT INTO

```
SELECT
    [Col1],
    [COl2]
INTO TableA
FROM TableB
```